# Deleted the dev/sda1 file and restarted the computer

Tags: boot, bios, development

I accidentally deleted /dev/sda1 file and restarted it and it says no bootable devices available please restart is there anything i can do now to get all my files back i can enter the bios mode

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you had, or why you're asking here, however my first step would be to boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and explore what is there. What was used by your /dev/sda1 partition (was it a a system partition, UEFI boot, or what as you've not specified).

Comment: Please be more specific. How did you delete the file, Which command did you use exactly?

Comment: 18.04 ubuntu There were two system partitions one was dev/sda1 and the other was dev/sda2 sda1 was 520 mb so I thought it would be some of the extra files I had so I deleted it and when I tried to restart it I realised it then after googling that I deleted something important now I can't open my desktop I have a lot of important files of eclipse and android studio. how can I turn it back on.

Comment: It wasn't a command I opened up the disks application and saw two partitions and deleted one of them

Comment: Try to restore with `testdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `testdisk` to **recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again**

Boot from Ubuntu usb-stick press CTRL+ALT+T and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install testdisk
testdisk
```

After this step follow steps/ instructions given on page  [TestDisk Step By Step](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

read it carefully before proceeding. If you choose wrong write option may loose data from other partitions too. Remember one thing let `testdisk` read and find all the partitions on your hard disk when you are sure it found all the partitions including deleted one. then proceed with write option. It may take long time in some cases.

Comment: Thank you I'll try this out.

Comment: @Arifa Shaik  Please update if it works for you.